# White screen after login in ionic1 app on ios build

Tags: iphone, xcode, ionic-framework

I am new to the ios builds using Ionic.
I have created the ionic build on IOS. It is showing the login screen. But after login it is showing me the empty white screen. I am not able to find the issue. I am also not sure how to debug this issue.

Please help me for this.

Comment: You should provide an example or code. May have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: may be because of route issue.check names of all controllers in js file with those in html files.check if app is working fine in browser or not

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, use following command to add platform for your ionic project 'ionic platform add android'.

'ionic platform add ios' doesn't support in windows.